# Very Basic Question in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql1="SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

echo '1234/' . $sql1 . "<br />";
```

Well the output is 1234/SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

but i want the output to be

```
1234/respective value
```

If possible give some explanation also

I am new to PHP ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to interface with a database. Read up the PHP documentation on databases.

Comment: It sounds as if you're unclear about how to extract data from a database using PHP. If that's the case, there are many print and online resources where you can learn. Try the book PHP and MySQL from O'Reilly.

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this? he said he's new to PHP and asked a legitimate programming question.

Comment: @sombe Seriously. I can remember reading my first PHP book without understanding what a database even was.  Everyone has to start somewhere and until you gain the vocabulary to ask the right questions, _all questions are valid._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not actually done a query, only defined the SQL query you intend to run as a string variable.  You need to establish a database connection, perform the query, and retrieve the result before your `respective value` will be what you want.

[Start reading the PHP MySQL manual here.](http://www.php.net/manual/book.mysql.php)

```
// Connect to your database
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("database_name");

// Perform the query
$sql1="SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Fetch the results - only one row in your case
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Use the $row result set to output your string.
echo '1234/' . $row['id'] . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thnxss ..i did connect to database not so dummy :)  But did not know about $result = mysql_query($sql);

// Fetch the results - only one row in your case
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);